# react-native-braintree-dropin-ui: lambda expressions are not supported in -source 7

Tags: reactjs, react-native, braintree

I'm using openJDK 11 on my machine. I recently updated react-native-braintree-dropin-ui package to the latest version. It now uses lambda expression in RNBraintreeDropInModule.java file. Therefore, when I run **npm run android** the build fails saying,

```
react-native-braintree-dropin-ui/android/src/main/java/tech/power/RNBraintreeDropIn/RNBraintreeDropInModule.java:41: error: lambda expressions are not supported in -source 7
            callback -> {
                     ^
  (use -source 8 or higher to enable lambda expressions)
1 error
```

Can someone help me with this? Thanks!

I tried setting VERSION_11 in app/build.gradle file but didn't work.

```
 compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_11
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_11
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I added

```
compileOptions { sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8 targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8 }
```

to android build.gradle of the braintree npm package. I used `patch-package` too to update the build.gradle prior to building the app.